# Autowiring by annotations

Tags: java, spring

`To support autowiring by annotations`, do I need to mention the `class` `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` in `spring.xml` file as follows

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

Comment: Why are you shouting?

Comment: No bean declaration is not required, refer spring documentation you will understand how to do it.

Comment: shmosel, sorry that was unintended, modified it.

Comment: thanks Chaitanya !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A default AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor will be registered by the "context:annotation-config" and "context:component-scan" XML tags.